# How to set expiration of tiles globally

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

How do I set the expiration of tiles globally in Geoserver? In the tilecache tab for a layer it says setting the value to 0 (default) uses the source setting. Where is this source setting set? I have tried altering geowebcache.xml but this is just per layer basis.